# Positioning relative and absolute boxes inside the Bootstrap 3 .well

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/4q8xXotYYi). Why am I not able to position the `#box-wrap` and its child element (`#box-1, #box-2, #box-3`) properly inside the Bootstrap 3 `.well`?

```css
#box-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
}

#box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:khaki;
}

#box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
#box-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="well"> 
      <div id="box-wrap">
        <div id="box-1"></div>
        <div id="box-2"><button class="btn btn-success">&gt;</button></div> 
        <div id="box-3"><button class="btn btn-success">&lt;</button></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What layout are you looking for exactly? Is it that the well doesn't surround the khaki `<div>`?

Comment: are you looking at having results like this? http://www.bootply.com/xoPhb7G6YJ --- else, what is the desired outcome/layout?

Comment: Hi Ochi, thanks this is working but how? I mean we should remove position: absolute; from the box-1 element? I didnt get this?

Comment: `position:absolute` can be tricky at times, specially when `div`s have `display:block` by default - I posted an answer explaining my changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If*** I understood your layout correctly, here's my solution.

I removed `position: absolute;` and changed the `box-2`, `box-3` from `div`s to `span`s (since divs have a `display:block` by default.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="well"> 
      <div id="box-wrap">
        <div id="box-1"></div>
        <span id="box-3"><button class="btn btn-success">&lt;</button></span>      
        <span id="box-2"><button class="btn btn-success">&gt;</button></span> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;

}

#box-1 {
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:khaki;
}
#box-2, 
#box-3 {
  background:khaki;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://bootply.com/xoPhb7G6YJ)**

**UPDATE** (Thx @ckuijjer)

Thanks to @ckuijjer for the comment. Here's ***his*** simpler version that accomplishes the same thing:

**Simplified HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="well"> 
      <div id="box-1"></div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">&lt;</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success">&gt;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Simplified CSS**

```
#box-1 {
    height:120px;
    background:khaki;
}
```

**[Simplified DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/YchLNw6siK)**

Comment: wow! compliments for understanding the question :). I think it can be even simpler, see http://www.bootply.com/YchLNw6siK

Comment: Yes, I chose not to simplify the CSS/HTML as I wasn't sure I had understood the layout quite fully :) -thanks for the simplified version, will update the answer for the benefit of others

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css as

```
#box-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    float:right;
    right: 5px;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://www.bootply.com/OFE1Ea208k)**

Comment: I think the issue is that the elements are not inside the `.well` your solution does not seem to address that

Comment: hi Tushar , Thanks for reply but this is not the point of the question! The problem is that why the boxes ate not posintinong inside the .well.

Answer (score 0):

Using
 `#box-1{
  position:relative;
}`

will solve the issue. 
I think as none of the parent element of box-1 has fixed height this is somehow affecting using position:absolute for a child div.